# What's the purpose of using ":" before a name in the path of a URL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

This might seem a trivial problem, but I have searched for a while for a concrete authoritative answer, but nothing came out so far.

I have been using express.js, and I have been seeing URLs' handlers with paths such as

```
app.get("/users/:id", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params)
})
```

or

```
app.get("/users/:name/photos", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params)
})
```

But I am not completely sure of the purpose of using `:` before `id` (or `name`) in those cases.

I know that, if I use `:` before `id`, `id` will be available as parameter of `req.params`, i.e. `req.params.id`. Usually `id` is an integer, but this is actually not strictly necessary, it could be anything else (e.g. string).

My guess about the reason of using `:` before a name in the path of a URL is simply to say to express that instead of `:id` or `:name`, we can pass whatever we want of any type. `:id` or `:name` are considered variables. Is this guess correct?

What are the purposes of using `:` when handling routing? When should we use it?

Answer (score 5):

The `:` just indicates a named variable as a placeholder in that part of the url. Without it, `id` would get matched literally in the url and would not be interpreted as a dynamic placeholder. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

You are right.

`:` is just used to set a route. It could have been a `!` or `@` or anything else for that matter. It declares a variable in route.

In your code:

```
app.get("/users/:id", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params)
})
```

`/users/:id` becomes a route. It means anything after `users/` will be caught by this handler and become available in the `id` variable inside it. It doesn't have to be an integer.

Here:

```
app.get("/users/:name/photos", function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.params)
})
```

The route is defined something like this:
`/users/john/photos/`

In this case, `john` is a variable which matched the route set.